# Swift - Compiler warns i haven't unwrapped an optional but then forces me to unwrap using ! rather than?

Tags: swift, xcode6, compiler-warnings, optional-values, forced-unwrapping

I've got an error in my code where the compiler gives a warning to unwrap an optional with the message

Value of optional type 'NSDate?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

My code is

```
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    let dob = currUser.valueForKey(userTextFieldKeyNames[i]) as? NSDate
    let dobText = formatter.stringFromDate(dob) //compiler says i need to unwrap dob using ! or ? ... but why am i forced to use ! rather than ? here
    field.text = dobText
```

I want to use ? to unwrap dob to allow the assignment to dobText to fail if dob is nil. The compiler's message indicates I can use ! or ? but it is only happy if I use dob! to unwrap. If I try to use dob? the compiler complains and forces me to use !.

If I force unwrap dob and it IS nil, won't that cause a crash in the formatter.stringFromDate(dob!) line. Can someone please explain what is going on here and the correct way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`formatter.stringFromDate(someDate)` takes an `NSDate` as a parameter and not an optional NSDate (`NSDate?`). Therefore, you need to either unsafely force unwrap it using `as!` or safely unwrap it using `if let` or the nil coalescing operator (`??`).

Comment: thx. so IS the crucial thing the fact that the stringFromDate method takes an NSDate and not an optional NSDate?  I was trying to apply a pattern in Matt Neuburgs book on downcasting and to "send a message to an Optional by optionally unwrapping the Optional" ie                                      let myDate: AnyObject = NSDate()
(myDate as? NSDate)?.description ..... this works ......but the difference seems to be that in my original question the dob was a (non-optional) parameter in the stringFromDate method

Comment: Yes, that is the essential reason as to why it wasn't working. Personally I would rather the function take an optional date which if it was nil would just return a nil optional string, but unfortunately that's not how it is.